# Vue Router Sidebar navigation item link changes while visiting inner pages

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

I have a SPA App in Vue JS, I have a side navigation bar which I want to stay visible for all pages. I have following links setup in side navigation bar

```
        {
            name: 'Overview',
            icon: 'ti-dashboard',
            path: 'overview',

        },
        {
            name: 'Areas',
            icon: 'ti-map-alt',
            path: 'areas',
        },
        {
            name: 'Assignments',
            icon: 'ti-check-box',
            path: 'assignments',

        },
        {
            name: 'Records',
            icon: 'ti-view-list-alt',
            id: 'third-party',
            children: [
                {
                    name: 'Vaccination',
                    path: 'vaccination',
                },
                {
                    name: 'Out-of-Area Vaccinations',
                    path: 'vaccination/outer',
                },
                {
                    name: 'Surveys',
                    path: 'survey',
                },
                {
                    name: 'Archived',
                    path: 'archived',
                },
            ],
        }
        ...
```

Following is my router setup

```
const routes = [
    {
        path: '/',
        component: App,
    },
    {
        path: '/login',
        component: require('../../../assets/js/components/Template/AppLogin.vue'),
    },
    {
        path: '/platform/projects',
        component: require('../../../assets/js/components/Template/Projects.vue'),
        meta: {requiresAuth: true},
    },
    {
        path: '/project/:projectId',
        component: require('../../../assets/js/components/Template/UIComponents/SidebarPlugin/SideBarNew.vue'),
        props: route => ({projectId: route.params.projectId}),
        children: [
            {
                path: 'overview',
                component: require('../../../assets/js/components/Template/mvdProjectOverview.vue'),
            },
            {
                path: 'areas',
                component: require('../../../assets/js/components/Template/AddVaccinationArea.vue'),
            },
            {
                path: 'assignments',
                component: require('../../../assets/js/components/Template/AssignAreaUsers.vue'),
            },
            {
                path: 'vaccination',
                component: require('../../../assets/js/components/Template/VaccinationRecord.vue'),
            },
            {
                path: 'vaccination/outer',
                name: 'projectOuterVaccinations',
                component: require('../../../assets/js/components/Template/OuterVaccinations.vue'),
            },
            {
                path: 'archived',
                name: 'projectOuterVaccinations',
                component: require('../../../assets/js/components/Template/ArchivedRecords.vue'),
            },
            {
                path: 'survey',
                component: require('../../../assets/js/components/Template/Surveys.vue'),
            },
            ...
```

```
const router = new VueRouter({
    routes,
    mode: 'history'
})
```

When I visit *vaccination/outer* All of my side bar navigation links are appended with *vaccination*

Attaching images for more clarity

1. Here the URL is good and should stay like this only

[image: Here the URL is good and should stay like this only]

2. When I navigate to *vaccination/outer*

[image]

3. The issue: Now all the links gets *vaccination* in between

[image]

I have a very basic knowledge of VUE ROUTER and ROUTER LINK. A help or guidance would be great. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am pretty sure you are using paths from presented array as: `<router-link to="LINK">some label</router-link>`. However, as your path values are not starting with `/` - vue router will add value of `to` property to the current URL instead of replace it.

Let's imagine I am on `/a/b/c` URL.
When I click on `<router-link to="dogs">Dogs</router-link>` - I will be redirected to the `/a/b/c/dogs`.
When I click on `<router-link to="/dogs">Dogs</router-link>` - I will be redirected to the `/dogs`.

All you need to do is, start paths with the slash. So instead of path: `vaccination/outer` use path: `/vaccination/outer` and it will work as you want to.

Comment: Hi Thanks for the info. I already tried that but then it turns my URL to "http://127.0.0.1:8000/vaccination/outer" instead of "http://127.0.0.1:8000/project/1068/vaccination/outer"

Comment: Isn't it a base URL? Have you tried to set it?: https://router.vuejs.org/api/#base

Comment: No! Base URL should be only 127.0.0.1:8000. I have not set any default Base URL in router config. I do need /project/1068/ for all pages which are related to project.

Comment: So build paths using computed: `/project/${this.$route.params.projectId}/rest/of/your/url`

Comment: Building the paths using computed worked. Thanks for the help!